# Print org-mode files

Tags: emacs, printing, org-mode

I'm wondering how you guys do print your org files from emacs? Like when you have a meeting and you can't bring your laptop so you quickly print your main TODO list to have something to work on!

Do you export org files to another format before printing? PDF? Latex? I find this to be messy output, I don't want a table of content when it's almost only TODO items.

Any advice would be useful!

Comment: Unrelated, we can't post question as wiki/community questions anymore?

Comment: I don't think so.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I print a nice HTML'ized version of my Org files, in such cases.

Have a look at my Bigblow theme therefore (see https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes).  I simply requires you to add a couple of lines into your Org file, and that's it.

Comment: This is a perfect answer as I've already tried HTML export to allow printing but I was a bit disappointed with the output. Your theme does quite a good job matching my way of organizing org files! Thx a lot for your contribution!

Comment: You're welcome. And I'll publish another HTML theme in the coming days hopefully. Very different, very elegant as well...

Comment: I already reported an issue on github with your Bigblow theme :), sure I'll have a look to the new one!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I remember how, I turn off the table of contents by putting this at the top of my org file:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

Then I usually export to HTML, open in a browser, select whatever I need from the file (avoiding headers/footers I don't like) and print the selection only.

Comment: Thx for the tips to avoid TOC!